# I want to check that $\left|\left|a+b\right|-\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\right|\leq2\left|b\right|\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R} $.

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

> I want to check that
>    $\left|\left|a+b\right|-\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\right|\leq2\left|b\right|\forall
>  a,b\in\mathbb{R}  $.

It 's equivalent to $\left|a+b\right|-\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\leq2\left|b\right|\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}
 $ and $-2\left|b\right|\leq\left|a+b\right|-\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}
 $.

The first statement: $\left|a+b\right|-\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\leq0
 $ so we are done.

The second statement is equivalent to $-\left|b\right|\leq\left|a+b\right|-\left|a\right|\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}\Longleftrightarrow\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\leq\left|a+b\right|\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}
 $

Do I have mistakes?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start. We have

$$ |a+b| \leq |a| + |b|, \\|a|+|b| \geq |a|-|b|   $$

$$ \implies | a+b| \leq |a| + |b|, \\ -(|a|+|b|) \leq -|a|+|b| $$

Adding the above inequalities gives

> $$  | a+b|-(|a|+|b|) \leq 2|b| . $$

Now, try to find the other inequality.

Comment: @chuyenvien94: You are very welcome.

Comment: and the other inequality is 

$|a|+|b|\le |a|+|b|$$\qquad$ and$\qquad$

$-|a+b|\le |b|-|a| $ (because $|a|-|a+b|\le |a-(a+b)|=|b|$)$\qquad$

so we get $\qquad$$|a|+|b|-|a+b|\le 2|b|$

Answer (score 2):

For any $a,b\in\mathbb R$, the following inequality holds.
$$|a|-|b|\le ||a|-|b||\le |a+b|.$$
The latter equality holds when $ab\le0.$
Hence, your first inequality is true.